# JQuery Image Slider Using "Cycle Plugin": Why Won't My Images "Cycle"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've built an image slider that is meant to transition between four images by fading in and out. I used the J Query plugin "Cycle" and set the effect to "fade". I'm also hoping to give the user the capability to pause the slideshow by hovering their cursor over the images, as well as control the flow with standard "next", "previous" buttons located in the top right hand corner.

Code is as follows:

Full Screen Result: 
http://jsfiddle.net/StacksOnStacksOverHoes/spL4W/3/embedded/result/

JS Fiddle Edit:
http://jsfiddle.net/StacksOnStacksOverHoes/spL4W/3/

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<title>slider</title>
<!-- Link to Google Jquery API -->
<!-- Link to Local Jquery-->
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.cycle.all"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="hero">
        <div id="pager"></div>
        <div id="pause"></div>
        <div id="play"></div>
        <div id="next"></div>
        <div id="prev"></div>
        <div id="slider_01">
            <div class="items">
                <div class="image_01"></div>
                <div class="info">
                     <h2>Hello World</h2>

                    <p>Hello world. <a href="#">Learn More</a>

                    </p>
                </div>
                <!--End of Info-->
            </div>
            <!--End of Items-->
            <div class="items">
                <div class="image_02"></div>
                <div class="info">
                     <h2>Hello World</h2>

                    <p>Hello world. <a href="#">Learn More</a>

                    </p>
                </div>
                <!--End of Info-->
            </div>
            <!--End of Items-->
            <div class="items">
                <div class="image_03"></div>
                <div class="info">
                     <h2>Hello World</h2>

                    <p>Hello world. <a href="#">Learn More</a>

                    </p>
                </div>
                <!--End of Info-->
            </div>
            <!--End of Items-->
            <div class="items">
                <div class="image_04"></div>
                <div class="info">
                     <h2>Hello World</h2>

                    <p>Hello world. <a href="#">Learn More</a>

                    </p>
                </div>
                <!--End of Info-->
            </div>
            <!--End of Items-->
        </div>
        <!--End of slider_01--> <a href="#">Previous</a>
 <a href="#">Next</a>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#hero {
    width: 960px;
    height: 500px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
}
#slider_01 {
    width: 960px;
    height: 500px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.info {
    width: 90%;
    height: 80px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: rgba(102, 204, 204, .2);
    z-index: 99;
}
.info h2 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 15px 0 0 20px;
    line-height: 1px;
}
.info p {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
    line-height: 1px;
}
#play {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 44px;
    background: rgba(102, 204, 0, .2);
    color: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 999;
}
#pause {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 88px;
    background: rgba(102, 204, 0, .5);
    color: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 999;
}
#next {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    background: rgba(102, 204, 0, .5);
    color: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 999;
}
#prev {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 133px;
    background: rgba(102, 204, 0, .5);
    color: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 999;
}
#pager {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 999;
}
#pager a {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
.image_01 {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 960px;
    height: 500px;
}
.image_02 {
    background-color: red;
    width: 960px;
    height: 500px;
}
.image_01 {
    background-color: green;
    width: 960px;
    height: 500px;
}
.image_01 {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 960px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

J Query:

```
$('#slider_01').cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    next: '#next',
    prev: '#prev',
    pager: '#pager',
    speed: 900,
    timeout: 3000,
    pause: 1,
});
```

Currently, over my code doesn't actually do anything as of yet, although all the components seem to be there. What am I missing?

Comment: You didn't import the Cycle plugin in Jsfiddle, nor did you activate jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

- You didn't import the Cycle plugin (External Resources) in Jsfiddle, nor did you activate
  jquery (Framework and extensions)
- When adding html to jsfiddle, add only the relevant html and strip out the head, body tag
- In your javascript, specify that you want your plugin to run on Document Ready

Html:

```
<div id="hero">
        <div id="pager"></div>
        <div id="pause"></div>
        <div id="play"></div>
        <div id="next"></div>
        <div id="prev"></div>
        <div id="slider_01">
            <div class="items">
                <div class="image_01"></div>
                <div class="info">
                     <h2>Hello World</h2>

                    <p>Hello world. <a href="#">Learn More</a>

                    </p>
                </div>
                <!--End of Info-->
            </div>
            <!--End of Items-->
            <div class="items">
                <div class="image_02"></div>
                <div class="info">
                     <h2>Hello World</h2>

                    <p>Hello world. <a href="#">Learn More</a>

                    </p>
                </div>
                <!--End of Info-->
            </div>
            <!--End of Items-->
            <div class="items">
                <div class="image_03"></div>
                <div class="info">
                     <h2>Hello World</h2>

                    <p>Hello world. <a href="#">Learn More</a>

                    </p>
                </div>
                <!--End of Info-->
            </div>
            <!--End of Items-->
            <div class="items">
                <div class="image_04"></div>
                <div class="info">
                     <h2>Hello World</h2>

                    <p>Hello world. <a href="#">Learn More</a>

                    </p>
                </div>
                <!--End of Info-->
            </div>
            <!--End of Items-->
        </div>
        <!--End of slider_01--> <a href="#">Previous</a>
 <a href="#">Next</a>
```

Javascript/JQuery:

```
//Document ready
$(function(){
    $('#slider_01').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        next: '#next',
        prev: '#prev',
        pager: '#pager',
        speed: 900,
        timeout: 3000,
        pause: 1,
    });
});
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/spL4W/7/)

Comment: My code is still not working when I run it anywhere besides JS fiddle. So I must have misunderstood what you said was incorrect about my original JQuery script. Are you saying to add "$(document).ready(function(){" as my first line of JS?

Comment: Check the Web developer tool's console of your browser to see if you have any errors. Something is probably not loading. Tell me what you see

Comment: Yes in order for the plugin to activate itself on page load, you must wrap your .cycle() call in the Document ready function '$(function(){ //Add the .cycle() code });'

Comment: I found this error message:
(Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined)

Comment: I found this error message:
(Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined)

I found this despite the fact that the I have now added the ".ready" function.

Comment: This means that jquery is not loaded in your page. Check the path to your jquery file. Also make sure that the jquery file is declared before the cycle file

Comment: It turned out to be the order the I was linking them in, just like you said. Thank You, very much.

Answer (score 0):

Working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/spL4W/8/

You didn't imported using fiddle, you were writing the  imports yourself, that is not how the fiddle works.

```
$('#slider_01').cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    next: '#next',
    prev: '#prev',
    pager: '#pager',
    speed: 900,
    timeout: 3000,
    pause: 1,
});
```

works just fine.
FYI
[jsfiddle tutorial](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCQQjBAwAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdoc.jsfiddle.net%2Ftutorial.html&ei=foXSU6mnDdOjugSaoYLwBQ&usg=AFQjCNEfoXGhP9ca88LP5Lli4tObWcjbdA&bvm=bv.71892024,d.c2E)